# Deadlock when using delete on postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I'm using postgres. I write code in java. Made a thread pool which periodically deletes rows from the database (deleteJobPeriodMs = 10 seconds):

```
long DELETEJOBPERIOD_MS_DEFAULT = 10000;
long deleteJobPeriodMs = userVariableDeleteJobPeriod.haveVariable()? deleteJobPeriodMsVar.getVariable(): DELETEJOBPERIOD_MS_DEFAULT;
executorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(coreThreadsCount, this::createDeleteJobThread);
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::deleteMethod, 0, 
deleteJobPeriodMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The `deleteMethod` uses the following request: `DELETE FROM field WHERE delete_date < ?`

At the same time, new entries are constantly being added to the program that require further deletion. No other operations are performed. Deadlock occurs about 5-10 times per hour of operation. Here's what I get in the logs:

```
2021-05-22 00:16:01 MSK [117890]: [1-1] ERROR:  deadlock detected
2021-05-22 00:16:01 MSK [117890]: [2-1] DETAIL:  Process 117890 waits for 
AccessExclusiveLock on tuple (17724,12) of relation 471906 of database 471895; 
blocked by process 116805.
    Process 116805 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1923461368; blocked by process 115793.
    Process 115793 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1923460316; blocked by process 109269.
    Process 109269 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1923457105; blocked by process 117890.
    Process 117890: DELETE FROM field WHERE delete_date < $1
    Process 116805: DELETE FROM field WHERE delete_date < $1
    Process 115793: DELETE FROM field WHERE delete_date < $1
    Process 109269: DELETE FROM field WHERE delete_date < $1
2021-05-22 00:16:01 MSK [117890]: [3-1] HINT:  See server log for query details.
2021-05-22 00:16:01 MSK [117890]: [4-1] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM jobs WHERE delete_date < $1
```

Part of one of the stacktrace:

```
Exception: operation: DeleteService.onDeleteFields, cause:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: deadlock detected
  Detail: Process 127116 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1610026614; blocked by process 6433.
Process 6433 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1610014636; blocked by process 5957.
Process 5957 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on tuple (3,5) of relation 471906 of database 471895; blocked by process 127116.
  Hint: See server log for query details.
  Where: while deleting tuple (3,5) in relation "field"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:132)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.postgresql.ds.PGPooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(PGPooledConnection.java:428)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
```

it is important to note that several of these applications are deployed on the same database

Comment: It would be good if you share the repository level code block to know whether the DB calling block lies within the transaction boundary and which type of transaction mechism used

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my problem. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the code. The default transaction mechanism is set as read committed (if I understood the question correctly). The same deletion operations do not occur in any part of the code, only here.

Comment: Can you include the definition of `deleteJobPeriodMs` in the question (the actual code)?

Comment: I'm inclide the definition for deleteJobPeriodMs. In my case, it is always used DELETEJOBPERIOD_MS_DEFAULT

Comment: "it is important to note that several of these applications are deployed on the same database". This is probably the issue. They're all trying to run the delete task concurrently.

Comment: Tim, please tell me if I change the request to DELETE FROM field WHERE  delete_date IN
(SELECT delete_date FROM field WHERE delete_date < ? FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED), can 
 this help from the concurrently for data or me need to think through the logic that gives the right to clear the database only to one of the instances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the request from `DELETE FROM field WHERE delete_date < ?` to `DELETE FROM JOBS WHERE  fid IN (SELECT fid FROM JOBS WHERE delete_date < ? FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED)`. At the moment, the error does not occur.